# Leap motion in MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion, mrtk

I tried all in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/supported-devices/leap-motion-mrtk?view=mrtkunity-2021-05) main step resource, but I cannot get leapmotion to work in MRTK.
I download the foundation packege with the [Mixed Reality Feature Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102778) but I keep getting this error in the editor while making the leap motion profile:
[image]

And this when I trytointegrate the module:
[image]

On the other hand when the core packege isimported as adviced "Only import the Core package within the Unity Modules" these errors appear and the project does not compile:

[image]

Unity version: 2020.3.11.f1 and installer both installers Leap_Motion_Setup_4.0.0+52173 (orion) and Ultraleap_Tracking_Installer_5.4.5_win64.

The departing repo is: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of MRTK are you using?

I see you've tried both Orion (V4 service) and Gemini (V5 service).

You need to match the correct version of the Ultraleap Unity Modules / Plugin with the correct version of the Ultraleap tracking service (Orion/Gemini). **Tracking Service version** >=5.2 should be used with the **Ultraleap Unity Plugin V5.3.0** (that exact version), although it will likely work with 4.9.1 of the Unity Modules too (I haven't personally tested this). This support is not yet in an MRTK release yet although it has been merged to main (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/pull/512).

**The update to the MRTK documentation to support the Ultraleap Unity Plugin V5 (requires V5.3.0 plugin) is in this pull request: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/pull/512 and is worth a read.**

Note, we talk about the V4 Unity code as **Unity Modules** and V5 Unity code as the **Unity Plugin**.

If you need to use the Orion tracking service then you need a Unity Modules version that is older than V4.9.1 - i.e. Unity Modules 4.8.0 from here https://github.com/ultraleap/UnityPlugin/releases/tag/UM-4.8.0

Sounds like you might still be having issues using Orion and Unity Modules - can you confirm the version of MRTK and Unity Modules you were trying to use please?

**Summary:**

**Orion Service V4.X** : Use <=V4.8.0 of the Unity Modules

**Gemini Service >= V5.2** : Use V4.9.1 of the Unity Modules or 5.3.0 of the Unity Plugin (support for the latter is not in an MRTK release but has been merged to main)